# AppStore - Build not found

Tags: ios, app-store

I archived a new version of application on XCode and uploaded it on app store using XCode , however when I open all builds from app store connect , I am not able to find the build. Thus I am not able to choose the build on the version. to submit for review.

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same issue as well, it has been 20 hours since I upload my build when I'm writing this and it's still nowhere to be seen.

I also tried to upload a second build and it's also not showing.

So I believe it's an Apple issue and not isolated, looks like we can only wait for now.

Edit: It works now. I assume it works for everyone now.

Comment: It didn't appear for me , did you re-upload it ? or the previous uploads appeared ?

Comment: I did re-upload. The previous upload did not resurface, but I did receive an email stating my 2 previous build (the missing ones) had invalid binary and therefore deleted, despite both of them being identical to the one I successfully uploaded except the build number.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this issue this morning. I have just now uploaded a new build of my app and the new build now appears, the missing one still doesn't appear. You will need to change the version number and re-archive your app, as otherwise it will be rejected as a redundant upload.

*Update* after 10 minutes the new build also disappears. Awesome..

Comment: I tried doing so , but it didn't appear though. Do you think there might be a problem today in the App Store connect ?

Comment: As you no doubt know by now, this issue was a temporary problem with the appstore connect service. Eventually the missing builds all appeared again. You weren't doing anything wrong. (Apple will only admit as much if you actually argue with their boilerplate responses..)

Answer (score 1):

After archieved file uploaded successfully it will go into processing stage. Where they are checking the internal settings using the automated tools.

Things will be checked like if any permission issues coming etc.

Lets say of example if you are using camera into your application but you have not given permission into.plist file than it will get failed into processing & removed build from the App Store.

Also if you have set up the permission properly but not given instructions that how & why this gets used than also build will get failed into processing stage. So there can be various reasons.

Ofcourse they will send you an email to your Admin email Id about the build failed while processing with the reason so by that you can resolve the issue.

Hope this will helps to everyone.

Comment: It is an update for an already app on the appstore , it just solved 2 bugs , so I didn't add anything in permissions. And I didn't receive a mail since then saying anything from apple , also I tried contacting them but they didn't reach me.